# Can you help me to understand how works sort() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, unicode

i know in general how works this method in javascript, but i haven't understand how order an array with UNICODE...

EXAMPLE:

```
var fruits = [
["caldera Cuicocha",1],
["Telica",2],    
];
```

I believed that the order did not change because the letter "c" preceding the letter "t"...

but with

```
fruits.sort();
```

the output is this:

```
//Telica
//caldera Cuicocha
```

would you be so kind as to explain to me why?
the calculation for unicode characters as happens?

Comment: Capital letters appear first in ASCII which is a subset of Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

`sort` compares strings by default. This means, `["caldera Cuicocha",1]` and `["Telica",2]` are both converted to strings first: `"caldera Cuicocha,1"` and `"Telica,2"`. Converting an `Array` to string is equivalent to `join`ing it with `,`.

Now you have correctly noticed that the sort is based on Unicode. Capital letters come *before* lower case letters, however:

```
Char  Hex-Code

   A  41
   B  42
   …  …
   Z  5A
   …  …
   a  61
   b  62
   …  …
   z  7A
```

`sort` sorts the array as expected with `"caldera Cuicocha,1"` coming *after* `"Telica,2"`.

Comment: A fine answer as far as it goes, but it would be nice to help the OP with advice about how to do what he appears to want to do.

Comment: The question was how sort works in JavaScript and this answers that exact question.

Comment: @rowland As I said, it's a "fine answer", but "it would be nice to...".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sorting function which will do what you want:

```
function sortfunc(a, b) {
    var cmpa = a[0].toLowerCase(), cmpb = b[0].toLowerCase();
    return cmpa < cmpb ? -1 : cmpa > cmpb ? +1 : 0;
}
```

In other words, take the first element of each of the two arrays, lower case it, then compare and return -1, +1, or 0, which is what `sort` expects back from its sort function. Then:

```
fruits.sort(sortfunc)
```

Comment: _"then compare and return -1, +1, or 0, which is what sort expects back from its sort function"_ Does `compareFunction` return different results if `Boolean` is returned ?

Comment: If you return `Boolean`, then `true` will be interpreted as meaning that the first element is greater than the second; `false` will be interpreted as meaning the the two elements are equal. This is unlikely to achieve the correct results.

Comment: _"This is unlikely to achieve the correct results."_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate different results between two approaches , integer , boolean, applied to same input array ? Can link to documentation , SO Question , Answer describing returning boolean at compare function of `.sort()` ?